# loading web page images after the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, pageload

In my website (that is for baby names), 40 names are shown in each pages, and each name can have a picture that are uploaded by users. 
now that number of names with pictures has increased my pages are very slow. by the way images are loaded from CDN and my concern is only for client side page load time.

first I decided to to put a 1x1 empty gif image as src and load actual images after the page load completes

```
<img src="x.gif" data-src="the-real-image-src.jpg" class="delayed-load" /> 

$(window).load(function () {
    $('.delayed-load').each(function(){
          $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('src'));
    });
});
```

but later I thought that as Images are being indexed by search engines it will have a bad influence on it. so I decided not to change real srcs and just cancel loading images before they start and retry loadin after page loaded. as I researched canceling image load doesn't prevent browser download te image so this one failed too.

I can add Images after page load too but it has the same problem as the first choice (that page source doesn't contain real image links.

what would you suggest to keep it both search engine friendly and also load images after page completion?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you're asking here -- the "page load" doesn't normally wait for images to be loaded. What specific behaviour are you seeing that you want to change? How are you measuring "client side page load time"? Can we see some code? Do you have width and height set on your `img` elements?

Comment: `.load` does wait. `.ready` doesn't.

Comment: Some browsers *cough*old ie*cough* will only render content "downwards", and so will wait until enough of the image has loaded to know the width and height before rendering downward content.

Comment: the problem is that page load time affects seo and I want to load images after the page is loaded.

Comment: So what you really are asking for is to reduce the time to "page ready" event?

Comment: I'm thinking you may be better off resizing and optimising the user-supplied images. I think perhaps some more concrete information would help -- how big are these images? What type are they? What's your page load speed actually looking like?

Comment: images are jpg and each about 10 KBs. my website is [www.nininam.com](http://www.nininam.com) if you want to have a look. and this is what alexa says about my website: Very Slow (6.085 Seconds), 96% of sites are faster.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, the `ads.php` is what slowed my load down, not the images.  My total load time was less than 4 seconds, and would have been closer to 2 without `ads.php`

Comment: well I'm doing same for ads but ads are not my concern as they are not really related to my website and I don't care about their indexing

Comment: 40 * 10KB doesn't sound like it should add up to six seconds, especially if they're coming from a CDN. You could probably shave off more than that just by implementing [compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) (which your server's currently not doing, by the looks of things...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `width="<value>"` and `height="<value>"` to your img tags (in pixels).  This will allow the page text content to render before the images are fully loaded.  No javascript required.

```
<img src="x.gif" width="42" height="60" data-src="the-real-image-src.jpg" />
```

Note that I assume either you have the same width and height for each image, or you've stored the metric somewhere you can access it on this load.

Comment: they actually have width and height that I have eliminated in example. but what it has to do with delayed loading of images?

Comment: Images are always loaded asynchronously.  The question is how do you get the rest of the page to render while the image is loading.  If the browser you are using (which you don't specify) is waiting until the images are at least partially loaded, theres not much to be done.

Comment: well as I want to reduce load time of my pages I don't pick a browser because users will use different kinds of browsers.

Comment: You might need to implement browser-specific strategies. You might start by targeting the browser most widely used on your site, or (if your concern is in fact SEO) what browser the engines you care about emulate.

Comment: well IE is used the most as google analytics says ( the browser that I have forgotten how it looked like)

Comment: by the way is it very bad to use my first strategy that I have mentioned in my question?

Comment: I don't know enough about SEO to answer that from an SEO perspective. From a UX point of view, I'm not sure it matters.  The load time of images is going to be roughly the same no matter how you do the loading, because it's based on the user's connection, browser and machine.  I am frankly surprised to hear that search engines care about load time, because that doesn't give much information about content quality.

Comment: I'm sure speed is an issue because google itself has informed. I don't want to change image load time. I know I can't change it but I want to move it after page is loaded so loading images won't count as page load time

Comment: @PaulProgrammer Google certainly uses page load speed as part of its algorithm, and have done [for a few years](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html). All else being equal, people want to see the content quickly when they click on a search result link. It's not the be-all and end-all; it's just one of many things considered for the ranking.